# Replacing the first space in each line with semi-colon on a file editor

Tags: regex, text-editor

I have a huge text file having:

[image]
How can I change the space coming after ID like 'GAXI01005455.1.1233' with semi-colon.
'GAXI01005455.1.1233 Bacteria' -> 'GAXI01005455.1.1233;Bacteria'

I can find the first space in each line using the regular expression pattern '^[^\s]*\s', but do not know filling "Replace with" box. All my attempts end in deleting 'GAXI01005455.1.1233'

Thank you,

Comment: You could use a capturing group `^(\S+)[^\S\r\n]+` and using the group in the replacement for example `$1;` or `\1;` See https://regex101.com/r/1hvHwI/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture in a group matching 1+ occurrences of a non whitespace char `(\S+)` followed by matching 1+ occurrences of a whitespace char except the newlines `[^\S\r\n]+`

In the replacement use the first capturing group followed by a semicolon.

```
^(\S+)[^\S\r\n]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1hvHwI/1)

Replace with

```
$1;
```